# How do I create a spinning wheel image using Ionic and Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am looking for a wheel directive, or javascript that implement a wheel, this wheel will be used in Ionic so it would be responsive. I found `ion-wheel` for ionic, it works well in the browser but in some devices it crashed.

I found this plugin : https://github.com/loringdodge/ionic-wheel-2, but the css crashed in all devices.
CodePen : http://codepen.io/loringdodge/pen/JYxByX
    Piece of code :

```
<ion-wheel>
      <div id="activate" ng-click="showCircles()"><i ng-class="circlesHidden ? 'ion-arrow-expand' : 'ion-arrow-shrink'"></i></div>
      <div class="circle"><i class="icon ion-home"></i></div>
      <div class="circle"><i class="icon ion-alert-circled"></i></div>
      <div class="circle"><i class="icon ion-heart-broken"></i></div>
</ion-wheel>
```

[image]

Any example for this issue?